# Rails and Digital Ocean Ubuntu Docker issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ssh, capistrano, digital-ocean

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma

But I get this error: 
root@demo:~/app # cap demo deploy:initial
[Deprecation Notice] Future versions of Capistrano will not load the Git SCM
plugin by default. To silence this deprecation warning, add the following to
your Capfile after `require "capistrano/deploy"`:

require "capistrano/scm/git"
    install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host x.x.x.x: Connection refused - connect(2) for "x.x.x.x." port 5000

Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "x.x.x.x" port 5000

I have been researching for a few hours and have no idea how to fix this as I cannot find a formulated answer.

Heres the deploy.rb

```
 server 'x.x.x.x', port: 5000, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

  set :repo_url,        'git@github.com:company/app.git'
  set :application,     'app'
  set :user,            'deploy'
  set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
  set :puma_workers,    0

  # Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
  set :pty,             true
  set :use_sudo,        true
  set :stage,           :demo
  set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
  set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
  set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
  set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
  set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
  set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
  set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
  set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/app.pub) }
  set :puma_preload_app, true
  set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
  set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

  ## Defaults:
  # set :scm,           :git
  set :branch,          :develop
  # set :format,        :pretty
  # set :log_level,     :debug
  # set :keep_releases, 5

  ## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
  # set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
  # set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

  namespace :puma do
    desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
    task :make_dirs do
      on roles(:app) do
        execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
        execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
      end
    end

    before :start, :make_dirs
  end

  namespace :deploy do
    desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
    task :check_revision do
      on roles(:app) do
        unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/develop`
          puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
          puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
          exit
        end
      end
    end

    desc 'Initial Deploy'
    task :initial do
      on roles(:app) do
        before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
        invoke 'deploy'
      end
    end

    desc 'Restart application'
    task :restart do
      on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
        invoke 'puma:restart'
      end
    end

    before :starting,     :check_revision
    after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
    after  :finishing,    :cleanup
    after  :finishing,    :restart
  end

  # ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
  # kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
  # kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Comment: Show your `deploy.rb`. Especially `set :ssh_options`

Comment: I updated the question with the deploy rb

Comment: Try to remove `.pub` from `ssh_options` `keys`.

Comment: still got connect refused, does the deploy.rb file need to be in the config folder or the deploy folder capistrano creates

Comment: Another question is why your keys file looks like `~/.ssh/app` and not `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Do you really have such a file on your local machine?

Comment: the file in that folder is app.pub and app I guess thats what I called it when I generated the file on the digital ocean server.

Comment: You don't need to create it on DO droplet. You need to create it (or use existing one) on local machine and use `ssh-copy-id` or manually copy your public key to your droplet.

Comment: So I have to take the ssh key I have on my local machine that I use to ssh in and put it in that folder? How do copy that into that folder?

Comment: Follow this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/initial-server-setup-with-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: Also try set `pty` to `false`. It can help.

Comment: Ok. I am working on this now. What is pty?

Comment: So I just had redone everything and still got a connection refused. So I guess the key I have on my local machine has a password and I cant transfer over to the server as a file only put the public key infoin the authorized_keys file. But then how do I do this last time: .cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh -p your_port_num deploy@your_server_ip 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'